Existence of a Dirac mass in the conditional laws of a couple
Let $\pi$ be the joint law of $(X, Y)$ with marginal distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$. We assume that we have: for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\mu(A) > 0$
$$
\nu\left(\{y \in \mathbb{R} : \pi_{Y=y}(A) = 1\}\right) > 0.
$$
where $\pi_{Y=y}$ is the conditional law of $X$ given $Y=y$.
I am asking if necessarily:
$$
\nu\left(\{y \in \mathbb{R} : \pi_{Y=y} \text{ is a Dirac measure}\}\right) > 0.
$$
This true if $X$ has atoms. I am unable to prove this in general or find any counterexample. Thank you very much for your help.
